# Interval notation for absolute value inequalities with variables on both sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I am trying to help my daughter with her algebra. She has the following problem;

$$|3x-6| \leq 5 - 2x  $$

I can solve it for the two possible answers, but then she needs to graph the answer and put the answer in interval notation form. Can anyone help me? The answers I get are $x \leq \frac{11}{5}$, or $x \leq 1$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $x\le \frac {11}5$ $\color{red}{\text{and}}$ $x\ge 1$.  Your answer implies $x$ can be any real number.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I typed my sign in backwards.

Comment: Actually, I didn't even notice that.  But there's a difference between saying $x\le \frac {11}5$ *or* $x\ge 1$ and saying $x\le \frac {11}5$ *and* $x\ge 1$.  In this case, you should have *and*.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality $|3x-6| \leq 5-2x$ means  $ 2x-5 \leq 3x-6 \leq 5-2x$.  The first inequality gives $x\geq 1$.  The second gives $x \leq \frac{11}{5}$, so this matches your response.  In interval notation, this would be written as $[1,\frac{11}{5}]$.   You can see what the graph would look like by plotting it on the number line.  I have done this for you here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%5Cleq+x+%5Cleq+11%2F5

Comment: Thank you very much!  I truly appreciate your response.

Comment: @BillGaylord No problem!  Keep this website in mind for any future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If we have that $a\leq x\leq b$, the interval notation for that is

$$[a,b]$$